# Getting manual for Steinberg Houston Contoller

Tags: download

Hi,

I am looking to get hold of a manual for the Steinberg Houston Controller. I tried to download it off of the Steinberg site but could not. Does anyone else have another source

Thanks

Comment: ftp://ftp.steinberg.net/Archives/Hardware/Houston/Docs_English - put that in your browser.  When it comes up, do not click on the manual link directly - you need to "save target". Their ftp site is a little funky, that's all.

Comment: @vcprod how come you're usin the comment box and not the answer. It's a perfect answer, how modest ;-)

Comment: @Andrew Eh, it seemed more related to a technical/web browser problem, and not a sound related issue - putting an answer would make it appear as a topic of discussion, not something already resolved.  And I'm very modest.  There is that.

Comment: @oinkaudio Realized you may not see there is an answer. Tag, you're it!

Comment: Haha. Thanks for the info and I did see your answer. 